# EOF Error :EOF when reading a line

Tags: python, eof

Please help me with this:

```
friends=[]
Max=0
i=0
while True:
   name=input().rstrip()
   if name=='stop':
       break
   friends.append(name)
   if len(name)>Max:
       Max=len(name)
       index=i
   i+=1
print(len(friends))
print(friends[index])
print(Max)
```

This code works when I execute it in my computer but it does not execute in skillrack

Comment: What is the python version expected by skillrack?

Comment: Skillrack works on the latest version of python(3.6.2)